# Why <!DOCTYPE html> changes width and height of my TDs in table, so table looks ugly?

Tags: html, size, width, html-table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset = windows-1251">
        <title>test export</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id = 'HTML_TableWithRoundedCorners0' position = 'STATIC' width = '200px' style = "height: 100px; "  cellspacing = '0' cellpadding = '0'>
            <tr>
                <td width = '7px' height = '7px'><img src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAYAAADEUlfTAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAkSURBVBhXYyAJbDhy7z8MQ4UgAFkCRRJdAi6JTQKEyZW89x8ASAFjfxv6A8oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' /></td>
                <td style = 'background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAANSURBVBhXY9hw5N5/AAfMA1I8e6yOAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); background-repeat: repeat;'></td>
                <td width = '7px' height = '7px'><img src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAYAAADEUlfTAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAkSURBVBhXY8ALNhy59x8ZQ4UhAF0SRQE2SRDGKwnC5Ere+w8AGz13ZexwuXoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style = 'background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAANSURBVBhXY9hw5N5/AAfMA1I8e6yOAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); background-repeat: repeat;'></td>
                <td align = 'LEFT' valign = 'TOP' style = 'background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAANSURBVBhXY9hw5N5/AAfMA1I8e6yOAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); background-repeat: repeat;'>&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td style = 'background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAANSURBVBhXY9hw5N5/AAfMA1I8e6yOAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); background-repeat: repeat;'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width = '7px' height = '7px'><img src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAYAAADEUlfTAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAkSURBVBhXY9hw5N5/XJgBBLBJgDCFkiCAVxIE8EqCAELy3n8Aob16tjPJVKEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' /></td>
                <td style = 'background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAANSURBVBhXY9hw5N5/AAfMA1I8e6yOAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); background-repeat: repeat;'></td>
                <td width = '7px' height = '7px'><img src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAYAAADEUlfTAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAdSURBVBhXY9hw5N5/XJjekgwggFMCBHBKMDAwAAB0+Y6cQEIaPgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==' /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

When there is no `<!DOCTYPE html>` the table looks fine, if this present, table looks ugly because of TDs incorrect size, while I even specified it to be 7px.
How I can solve it?
I test it in IE11

Comment: Not really answering your question - but you could do it with `CSS` instead of images - http://jsfiddle.net/98krC/ (Depends on what you need this for though I guess.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In quirks mode (AKA compatibility-with-1990s-bugs mode), line height calculations are broken so the space below the image (which is supposed to sit on the baseline, not the descender line) is missing.

Adding the Doctype prevents triggering quirks mode.

[image: typographic lines]

You can work around it by setting `display: block` on your images.

You should deal with the problem by not using tables for layout in the first place; support for [border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) is pretty good these days.

Comment: Sadly, border-radius is not supported by IE8, while it the highest IE for XP. So I will try `display: block;` solution.

Comment: This is a minor cosmetic detail. It should not matter that it degrades down to rectangular corners on a IE8. Windows XP isn't even supported with security updates any more, anyone using it has bigger problems to worry about than a lack of rounded corners!